# What is considered as full ID of a tag/element?

Tags: html, syntax, attributes

Is there some logic that whenever some javascript method requires ID as input that is has to be in explicit format #ID?

For example many of javascript libraries state that use ID as input and since input is implicitly ID then why there's need to prepend #?

For me the ID is just the ID and not the explicit format #ID in which # is more of an CSS syntax dependency and shouldn't be required in javascript solutions which require ID as input.

I'm just wondering that is ID format opinionated or based on some specification?

Comment: An example would help explain your question.

Comment: Totally opinionated. But the simplest way to target **one** specific element, since ID must be unique.